# Is the covariant derivative a tensor?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

While studying general relativity, the covariant derivative is constructed (in no rigorous manner) in order to make the derivative of a tensor transform like a tensor. Symbolically, $$ \nabla'_{\mu} V'^{\nu}=\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial x'^{\mu}} \frac{\partial x'^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\sigma}} \nabla_{\rho} V^{\sigma}.$$ The new derivative is given by $$ \nabla_\mu V^\nu=\partial^{}_\mu V^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu \rho} V^\rho.$$ The transformation law in the first equation is that of a 2-nd rank tensor. Does that mean the derivative should transform as a $(0,1)$-tensor? If so, I don't see how that is because I don't see how the covariant derivative can be thought of independently without acting on any tensors after it. So I can't write the transformation law for it alone. Does it even make sense to think of it independently in that manner?

Comment: Sure, tensor operators are a thing. Just like how $\nabla = (\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z)$ was a vector operator and could interact with other vectors through familiar operations. However, commutativity is lost - for example $\nabla\cdot V$ is a divergence but $V\cdot \nabla$ is a directional derivative.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That's essentially what covectors are introduced in linear algebra to be; linear maps. And we can generalize that to arbitrary rank tensors. What I can't figure out is how to write the transformation law for the covariant derivative. Moreover, it's written as a sum of two parts, $\partial_{\mu}$ which transforms like a covector, and $\Gamma$'s which don't transform like tensors. So how can the derivative as a whole be a tensor? But when we combine them and act on a vector, the non-tensorial parts cancel out and we get a tensor, which is the whole point.

Comment: You seem to be missing your whole point about the "nontensorial part" canceling out. $\partial_\mu$ is not a tensor. And you can write the transfomation law for the covariant derivative by itself, it's just chain rule hence it comes out in front.

Comment: $\partial_{\mu} V^{\nu}$ is not a tensor. But $\partial_{\mu}$ on its own transforms like one. That's why I was asking about considering $\nabla$ independently vs considering its action on a tensor.

Comment: One useful definition of a $(0,1)$ tensor $\omega_a$ is that for any vector field $X^a$ the contraction $\omega(X)=\omega_aX^a$ is *tensorial in $X$*, in that at a point $p$, the value $(\omega_aX^a)(p)$ is determined by $\omega$ and $X(p)$. This is not the case for $\nabla$.